# How can I execute IPP v3 CDCQuery?

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I find documentation and objects in IPP .Net V3 for CDCQuery, but can't seem to make it work.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
QueryService<Intuit.Ipp.Data.CDCQuery> myQueryService = new QueryService<Intuit.Ipp.Data.CDCQuery>(myServiceContext);

DateTime updateDate = new DateTime(2013, 10, 30);

var recs = myQueryService.Select(c => c).Where(c => c.ChangedSince > updateDate);
foreach (var rec in recs)
{
    // do something with the results...
}
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what is working for me.

```
            // Not used, but shown anyway...
            CDCQuery cdcQuery = new CDCQuery();
            cdcQuery.ChangedSince = dtUpper;

            // This does the work...
            DataService commonService = new DataService(context);
            List<IEntity> lstEnt = new List<IEntity>();
            lstEnt.Add(new Customer());
            IntuitCDCResponse cdcResp = commonService.CDC(lstEnt, dtUpper);
            if (cdcResp.entities.ContainsKey("Customer"))
                foreach (Customer qboi in cdcResp.entities["Customer"])
                {
                }
```

Best Regards